# Mule Studio - difference in APEX method that gets populated in Mule 3 Vs Mule 4

Tags: salesforce, mule, apex, mulesoft, anypoint-studio

I am migrating an existing Mule 3 application to Mule 4

Mule 3 is making an APEX GET call
Here is the source code for Mule 3:

```
<sfdc:invoke-apex-rest-method 
   config-ref="SFDC_config" doc:name="Salesforce: EmpMaintenanceDetails  GET call"   
    
restMethodName="EmpMaintenanceDetails||getEmpMaintenanceDetails^/services/apexrest/EmpMaintenanceDetails/
        #[flowVars.empId]?id=#[flowVars.empId]^HttpGet^application/json^" />
```

However in case of Mule 4 there is a slight difference in the method that gets autopopulated :

```
<salesforce:invoke-apex-rest-method 
 config-ref="SFDC_config" doc:name="SF EmpMaintenanceDetails GET call" 
 className="EmpMaintenanceDetails"
methodName="getEmpMaintenanceDetails^/EmpMaintenanceDetails/*^HttpGet^void^" />
```

if you see there is a difference in how the two appear in Mule 3 vs Mule 4
what is weird is that though this APEX REST call is expected to return a response Mule 3 signature is void ( which seems wrong ) Vs Mule 4 signature of application/json seems correct

So I am not sure why we see these differences ? Is this just because of how metadata propogates from SFDC to Anypoint studio in Mule 3 Vs Mule 4 ?